# Ecto query with a joined table not sorting by joined column

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have an Ecto query that performs a left join to retrieve a status description, and then
I want the query to do an `order by` on that status description. Here's my code:

```
query = from p in "pt_data",
  left_join: s in "pt_status", on: s.status_code == p.status,
  select: %{
    rec_id: p.rec_id,
    status: p.status,
    status_descr: s.descr,
    name: p.name
  }

recs = Enum.reduce(criteria, query, fn
  {:sort, %{sort_by: sort_by}}, query ->
    [sort_by, direction] = String.split(sort_by, ":")
    sort_by = String.to_existing_atom(sort_by)
    direction = String.to_existing_atom(direction)
    from [p, s] in query, order_by: [{^direction, ^sort_by}]
  end

  {_, _}, query -> query
end)
|> Repo.all
```

If I set the `sort_by` value to `"descr:asc"` and run this code, I get an *"ERROR 42703 (undefined column) column d0.descr does not exist"* message. Apparently the actual column is `d1.descr` instead.  How does one use joined columns in an `order by` clause when having the Ecto query produce a Map result?
What am I missing?

Comment: Should not it be the alias `status_descr:asc` instead? Otherwise there would be a uncertainty if `pt_data` also had `descr` column. _Sidenote:_ `%{sort_by, sort_by}` is an invalid syntax.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo - fixed it.  I've managed to get a working sort by setting up a `case` statement to test the `sort_by` value and produce an entirely new `from` line for each case. It seems that the sticking point is with putting a value such as `s.descr` into the `sort_by` variable - I've not found a way to do that.